# Using one instance of a viewController class in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I am writing an iOS7 app in Xcode 5 with storyboards. In a part of the app, I need three screens that shared the same `viewController` class. These screens are `UIViewControllers`. I use a `UISegmentControl` to go from screen to screen based on conditions. I disabled the control if the user had not completed certain steps.

I used a `BOOL` value check if certain steps had been completed and set its value to `YES / NO.`

The problem is when I want to go back to the last screen - I am getting a new instance of my viewController class. This has two problems:

1. Memory grows each time the user goes between the two views
2. BOOL value and all other properties are nil when new instance loads.

In my segment control this is how I get to the views:

```
-(void)segmentcontrol:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{

    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        {

   self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"stepOne"];
        [self presentViewController:self.viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
    else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 ){
        self.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"stepTwo"];
        [self presentViewController:self.viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }else {
    }
}
```

This `viewController` is a subclass of my `BaseViewController` - which I used for UI elements that is constant across all screens.

What I want to do is return the same instance of the `viewController` class when I change the segment control to a another view, using the same class.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: The `UITabBarController` holds all the properties you want, you can use it without the `UITabBar` itself, and use the segmentControl to switch between them. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544005/uitabbarcontroller-without-a-uitabbar) for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear why you're using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` but it looks like you're doing things in the wrong way.

What you want to be doing is creating a container controller. So, the view controller which hosts the segmented control creates a number of view controller instances and adds them as child view controllers. Now, when the segments are selected you get the child at the selected index, remove the old view controllers view from its superview and add the new view controllers view as a subview.

You don't need to do it like that, but it will probably be cleanest. Your memory grows currently because you use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`. All you really need to do is to keep an array of view controllers and reuse instead of recreating. That said, continually presenting view controllers is not wise.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. The reason I need to reuse the view controllers is if the user goes back to change details on the last view controller. Since all these view controllers do the same job, using one class for all three made sense to me. I'll do some reading on how to implement what you suggested above. Thank you.

Comment: One class perhaps, but multiple instances. The key is to keep a list of the instances so you can redisplay when required.

Comment: Okay. I will see if I can get it to work. Appreciate your help.