# UIScrollView and Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am testing out something I would like to have in my app. I have a UiViewController in a storyboard that has a UIScrollView - I now want to add other viewControllers to this scrollView and swipe between them.

I would like to add a view that I made in the storyboard into this UIScrollView. Is it possible?

I tried something along the lines of:

```
MYViewController *viewOne = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myView"];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:viewOne.view];
```

I've set the the scrollView size to be bigger than the screen and when the main view loads, I can see there is a scroll view (the scroll bars show) but my viewController is not inside it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is still not right, on a couple of levels.

First, you should not use alloc/init for view controllers. You either need to use `initWithNibName:bundle:` (to create a view controller from a nib file) or `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to load a view controller from a storyboard.

Second, you should not add a view controller's view as a subview of another view controller unless you use the parent/child view controller support that was added in iOS 5 and greatly improved in iOS 6. If you do what you are doing then all sorts of things won't work correctly: Auto-rotation, low memory warnings, background notifications etc. The list of things that can go wrong is unbounded.

The easiest way to do this is to add a container view as a frame to hold your child view controller, and then control-drag from your container view onto the scene that you want to set up as a child. This causes IB to set up and "Embed" segue. Embed segues do all the housekeeping you need to host one view controller's content inside another, with no code needed.

You could create a container view inside your scroll view's content view, and then it would just work fine.

Comment: Hi Duncan, 
See my previous SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453513/using-one-instance-of-a-viewcontroller-class-in-storyboard/21453949?noredirect=1#comment32374767_21453949

I though a UiScrollView would be easier to get the effect I was looking for?

Comment: To add: I wanted a scrollview so I could swipe between the views that I needed to and use segmentcontrolt o go straight to a view that the user wanted

Comment: Tander, what you should really do is use a UIPageViewController. That does everything you want, and much more neatly than what you are trying to do. You can set it up to swipe between pages, or do page curl. You can also easily add a page control, which lets the user tap to switch, and the page view controller manages the page control for you. Much cleaner and a more familiar UI.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

I was not allocating and initialising my viewController. Ooops.

This is the correct code:

```
BaseViewController *viewOne = [[BaseViewController alloc]init];
    viewOne = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myView"];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:viewOne.view];
```